# Refactor: Preserve the original state with Nextjs using localStorage?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How do you preserve a react/nextjs state on page load then to compare a state change? This is not a question on how to compare previous state, but rather the original state. I feel this can be refactored to use a lifecycle hook?

On page load, I want to save a snapshot of the state, presumably in localStorage then I compare when data is changed. So far my way of doing it works but.... I feel this is wrong. Can [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/compare-original-state-wpktk) be refactored? Also, `changes` is `true` on few page refreshes but can't replicate in the sandbox. Weird. On first page load, `changes` should never be `true`, that's what I want.

Code sample  [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compare-original-state-wpktk)

Comment: On first render localStorage value would be null and state's value will be default, Since they will be unequal, changes should be `true, No ?

Comment: That sound about right. So, can this be refactored so that it's always `false` on page reload? I only need to compage the original state. Not sure where else to save this. Cookie?

Comment: How about you make change variable false, if localStorage is empty too ?

Comment: I was thinking about that. Let me see what I can come up with then make another reply. Thanks

Comment: @Mobeen I've managed to use `shouldComponentUpdate()` and that seem to do the trick. The issue was that state was on set on initial page load and I had to delete the localStore before setting it. See updated sandbox.